# Rails displays wrong date for object's created_at and updated_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a problem in my application. I am making a simple CMS and I need to display posts' creation date. What I am doing now doesn't work correctly. It displays time correctly, but not the date. For every entry it shows that the date is 20th October, although it is not.

I checked my db via `rails c`, it stores correct values. So the issue must be somewhere in displaying code.

Here is how I output it:

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
  <h3 class="article-title"><u><%= link_to article.title, article %></u></h3>
  <p><%= article.text.html_safe %></p>
  <div class="article-info">
    <p>Posted on <em><%= article.updated_at.strftime("%A, %C %B %G %R") %> </em> by <em><%= article.user.username %></em> |
    <%= link_to 'Comments...', article %>
    <% if user_signed_in? and article.user == current_user %>
       | <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article) %>
       | <%= link_to 'Destroy', article, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you certain you want to delete this?' } %> </p>
    <% end %>
    </div>
    <% if article.tag_list.any? %>
      <div class="article-tags">Tags: <%= raw article.tag_list.map { |tag| link_to tag, tag_path(tag)}.join(", ") %></div>
    <% end %>
  <hr />
<% end %>
```

What can cause such a behaviour?

Comment: Read about strftime and explain to us your format "%A, %C %B %G %R"

Comment: @Meier oh, I see now. I thought `%C` was a day of the month, but it is actually is a year divided by 100. It should be `%d` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Problem is the strftime attributes:

```
<%= article.updated_at.strftime("%A, %C %B %G %R") %>
```

> %A - The full weekday name (`Sunday'') 
>   %C - year / 100 (round down. 20 in 2009) 
>   %B - The full month name (`January'') 
>   %G - The week-based year %R - 24-hour time (%H:%M)

You need to use the this:

```
<%= article.updated_at.strftime("%A, %d %B %Y %R") %>
```

> %d -  %d - Day of the month, zero-padded (01..31)
>
> %Y - Year with century

[APIdock - DateTime](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime)

Answer (score 1):

use this format in your code

```
<%= article.updated_at.strftime("%A, %d %B %Y %l:%M%p") %>
```